# finding and placing a word from the text in an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a word in the text with my name. The code requires me to first find the first character of the word and then subsequently push the remaining letters in the hits[] array. I am trying but got stuck.

```
var text = "This is just Rohit.";
var myName = "Rohit";
var hits = [];
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] === myName[0] )
        {
            for(j = 0; j < myName.length; j++)
            {
                hits.push(text[i]);
            }; 
        };
    };

hits;
```

Comment: Do you need to get array or just find your name? Maybe this can help you: `"This is just Rohit.".indexOf("Rohit")`

Comment: @Lends this looks/sounds like a homework question to me. :) @goldensquare Your inner for loop is starting at 0 again, shouldn't you be starting at `j = i`?

Comment: Hmmm, I see what you're getting at but have you looked into [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)? You can only grab one result at a time but then you can cut the string accordingly.

Comment: Why don't you use split method to split the phrase into words?
`var text = "This is just Rohit."; 
arr=text.split()//arr=['This','is','just','Rohit'] `

Also please define a bit better what you want your program to do

Comment: right now my goal is to solve this as it is. and please just paste the whole code. I will understand it.

Comment: Also by the way you compare every time you see the first letter capital R in your example, it will go inside even if the word is not the one you want.

Comment: We may need to have a discussion on how to ask questions on stack overflow. What you actually want and what you're asking for are 1) two different things and 2) a lot like a homework problem. Personally, I think it's bad form to ask people who are willing to help solve problems to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = "This is just Rohit.";
var myName = "Rohit";
var hits = [];
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if(text[i] === myName[0] ) {
            for(var j = i, l = 0;  l < myName.length; j++, l++) {
                    hits.push(text[j]);
            }
    }
}

console.log(hits.join(''));
```

Comment: Updated it, give it a go now.

Comment: second 'for' loop should stop when it reaches its current point in the string + myName.length.

Comment: Last update...you should probably figure out how to do this on your own though. :)

Comment: that's not how arrays work, you've asked how to push, I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to join an array into a string. This comment itself should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help.Let me know if a change is needed.

```
var text = "This is just Rohit.";
var myName = "Rohit.";
var hits = [];

var array1=text.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
{
   if(array1[i]==myName)
   {
      hits.push(array1[i].split(''));
   }
}
```

THIS PART IS THE METHOD WHICH YOU WERE USING::

```
var text = "This is just Rohit.";
var myName = "Rohit";
var hits = [];
var x='';
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] === myName.charAt(0) && text[i-1]==" " )
        {
            for(j = i; j < (i+myName.length); j++)
            {
                console.log(text[j]);    
                x=x+text[j];
            }
        }
    }

hits[0]=x;

alert(hits);
```

Comment: @Goldensquare i think the second part should help!

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your comments for clarification, it looks like you just want your name as the only element in a new array.

Use this:

```
var text = 'Your name is Rohit.';
var name = 'Rohit';
var hits = [text.substring(text.indexOf(name), text.indexOf(name) + name.length)];

console.log(hits);
// ["Rohit"]
```

Can't imagine how this is helpful, but the code above will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the searchtext and go with the searchterm.

```
var hits = []; 
var i=0; 
while (i<"Rohit".length) arr.push("Rohit"[i++]);
console.log(hits); 

// ["R", "o", "h", "i", "t"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it.

```
var text = "This is just Rohit.";
var myName = "Rohit";
var hits = [];
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] === myName[0] )
        {
            for(var j = i; j < (myName.length+i); j++)
            {
                hits.push(text[j]);
            }; 
        };
    };

hits;
```

Comment: If you're going for form, you should remove the semicolons around your for and conditional blocks. Also, it generally considered bad conduct to take someone else's answer that works and modify it slightly (and illegibly) and post it as your own answer.

Comment: hey I found the bug myself. I am not saying that your answers were wrong. But this was the way i wanted it.

Comment: To be fair, you didn't find the bug yourself, you asked a bunch of people to solve it for you, who have obviously been writing javascript a lot longer than you, so it's generally good practice to take their advice and understand what's going on.

Comment: I am learning javascript. I can't learn the new keywords all at once.

Comment: Just curious, `hits` is still going to be an array, so it won't be `"Rohit"`, how are you handling that?